# Proving the Inequality: $\displaystyle 3( a^2 + b^2 + c^2+d^2) + 4abcd \geq 16$ subject to constraint $ a+b+c+d=4.$

Tags: inequality, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

> $$ \displaystyle \ \text{Prove} \  3( a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2) + 4abcd \geq 16 \ \text{subject to constraint} \  a+b+c+d=4 .$$

While I was going through this question [Solving Inequality using Lagrange Multiplier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404765/let-a-b-c-be-nonnegative-reals-with-a-2-b-2-c-2-abc-4-prove-that), I became aware of this technique. So I tried to use it in this Question.

---

**My Approach:**

First I defined a constriant function $\displaystyle g(x) = a+b+c+d $ and a constraint set $$\displaystyle \bar{S} = \{ x \in \bar{U} : g(x) = 4 \}\\
\text{where} \ \bar{U} = \{ (a,b,c,d) : a+b+c+d \leq 100 \} $$

Now to the next step: Defining objective function $\displaystyle f(x) = 3( a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2) + 4abcd .$

Also $g$ and $f$ are polynomial function, thus they are continuous.

### *Case $1:$*

The minimum of $f$ lies on the boundary of the set $\bar{S}$, hence atleast one of the component of $\displaystyle g(x)$ is equal to zero.

Thus we are left to prove $\displaystyle 3( a^2 + b^2 + c^2 ) \geq 16 $ given that $a+b+c=4.$ This is the immediate result of **Chauchy Swartz Inequality**.

### *Case $2:$*

Here we assume that minimum of $f$ lies inside set $\bar{S}$  $ ( \text{or} \ x \in S)$. Then using the Lagrange multiplier theorem:

The Lagrange Function here is $\displaystyle \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) = f(x) - \lambda g(x)$.
Thus to find local extrema of a Lagrange Function :

$$\displaystyle \nabla \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) = 0 \implies \nabla f(x) = \lambda \nabla  g(x) \\
$$

$$\displaystyle 
\left[
\begin{array}[c]
*6a+ 4bcd \\
6b + 4acd \\
6c + 4abd \\
6d + 4abc \\
\end{array}
\right ] 
= \lambda 
\left[
\begin{array}[c]
*1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right ] 
$$

And the only case that satify this condition is the one with $a=b=c=d.$

Thus satisfying the constraint function $g(x) = 4,$  we get $a=b=c=d=1$ and then $ \displaystyle f(x) = 16 $.

And as the second partial derivative $\displaystyle \nabla^2 \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) = 6,$ we conclude that $(1,1,1,1)$ is minimum of $f(x).$

---

Please correct me, if I am wrong or if there is something missing to check cause, I am new to this topic. And I want to ask if I am right: *Lagrange function is the family of functions passing through the intersection of the two given functions (according to my knowlege of co-ordinate geometry).*

Comment: An elementary method is to suppose WLOG that $a\ge b\ge c\ge d.$ Now fix $c,d$ and $a+b$. Then $df/da>0$ unless $a=b$. Similarly, fix $a,d$ and $b+c$. Then $df/db>0$  unless $b=c$. Two more steps like this and you know $\min f$ can only occur at $a=b=c=d$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you, will think about it. But I want to know if I am on the right track here. This is actually my first attempt to silve inequality with this method

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi You need $a, b, c, d \ge 0$.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi Also, "And the only case that satify this condition is the one with $a = b = c = d$" is not true. For example, $a = 4 - (3/2)\sqrt 6, b = c = d = (1/2)\sqrt 6$ and $\lambda = 24 - 6\sqrt 6$ is another solution to the equations.

Comment: @RiverLi Yes we have the condition is $a,b,c,d \geq 0$. Thank you for the other solution will try to find it out.